# Split list into a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing

I have a list of datetime objects that looks like the following:

```
print(dates)

>>[array([Timestamp('2022-09-26 00:00:00', freq='15T'),
        Timestamp('2022-09-26 00:15:00', freq='15T'),
        Timestamp('2022-09-26 00:30:00', freq='15T')], dtype=object),
 array([Timestamp('2022-09-27 00:00:00', freq='15T'),
        Timestamp('2022-09-27 00:15:00', freq='15T')], dtype=object)]
```

I want to create a dataframe df and use these dates as index. However, since dates is a list with more than one array, I'm not able to do it.

My approach towards similar issues was using pd.concat, however I get the following error for this specific case:
"cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid"

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.vstack(dates)
df.index = idx
```